# Prevent ajax request till new token is obtained

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have implemented refresh token functionality for my WEB API due to which a user can get a new token using a refresh token.

Whenever API returns unauthorized status code, I need to get new token and updated all the pending request with that new token. But instead of that, some ajax request send API request with old token as new token is not obtain yet and the request of new token is in progress.

I want a way to prevent this request till new token is not obtain. Also, I have used a third party javascript library so I cannot set async to false as this will harm the performance of system.

**UPDATE:**

Resolved the issue by adding below logic. Hope this can help others.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (opts, originalOpts, jqXHR) {
// you could pass this option in on a "retry" so that it doesn't
// get all recursive on you.
if (opts.refreshRequest) {
    return;
}

// our own deferred object to handle done/fail callbacks
var dfd = $.Deferred();

// if the request works, return normally
jqXHR.done(dfd.resolve);

// if the request fails, do something else
// yet still resolve
jqXHR.fail(function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
        $.ajax({
            url: BASEPATH.APIPATH + '/Token',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            refreshRequest: true,
            error: function () {
                // reject with the original 401 data and then redirect to login page.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location = "/Login";
                }, 4000);
                dfd.rejectWith(jqXHR, args);
            },
            success: function (res) {
                // retry with a copied originalOpts with new access token.
                var newOpts = $.extend({}, originalOpts, { url: opts.url });

                // pass this one on to our deferred pass or fail.
                $.ajax(newOpts).then(dfd.resolve, dfd.reject);
            }
        });

    } else {
        dfd.rejectWith(jqXHR, args);
    }
})

return dfd.promise(jqXHR);});
```

Answer (score -2):

Engage your javascript with below code for specific time until server generate new token.

```
function wait(ms) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + ms) {
        end = new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

wait(5000);  //5 seconds

In wait function, you can specify the time taken by the server to generate token. Please vote if it will help you.

Comment: This is not useful because all the requests are sent to API asynchronously and I want to prevent them when the first request callback is obtain and it fail to authorize.